# How do you retrieve an author's photo via Blogger API?

Tags: api, blogger

I already know how to retrieve the blog data via the email and password of a user, but looking through the returned feed, I don't see the user's profile photo.

Is there any way to retrieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer : No.

But probably you could do something with this URL, it will give you the profile picture of someone's Google Plus account

```
https://plus.google.com/s2/photos/profile/{user_id}
```